# How to group results by 2 values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[.NET Frameworks] => Array (
    [WPF] => Array (
        [user1] => No Knowledge
        [user2] => No Knowledge
    )
[) Java Frameworks] => Array (
    [Hibernate] => Array (
        [user1] => No Knowledge
        [user2] => Solid Understanding
        )
    )
[PHP Frameworks] => Array (
    [CakePHP] => Array (
        [user1] => Some Knowledge
        )
    [CodeIgniter] => Array (
        [user1] => Solid Understanding
        [user3] => Solid Understanding
        [user2] => No Knowledge
        [user4] => No Knowledge
        )
    [Pear] => Array (
        [user1] => Some Knowledge
        )
    )
[Web] => Array (
    [HTML] => Array (
        [user1] => Solid Understanding
        )
    )
```

**Context:**
Every skill group (e.g. .Net Frameworks) can have multiple skills (e.g. WPF) and every skill can have multi users of which each have their own competency.

And I'm trying to get it to look like this [image]

However I keep getting appended user names to the end of the  output breaking the table layout or the user name is missing all together. As you can see here [image]

This is my view code

```
if( !empty($skills) )
    {
        $skill_group_name = '';
        $counter=0;
        //var_dump($skills);
        foreach ($skills as $row)
        {
             $section[$row['skill_group_name']][$row['skill_name']][$row['name']] = '<td>'.$row['competency_name'].'</td>'; //build entire section based on skill 
             $userID[$row['name']] = $row['user_id']; //get user id
        }
            $staff_name = '';
            $countStaff = '';

        foreach($section as $title => $all)
        {

            // Wrap it
            echo '<div class="panel panel-default">'."\n\r";
            echo '<div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" data-target=".skill'.++$counter.'" data-toggle="collapse">'."\n\r" . $title;
            echo '</a></div>'."\n\r";

            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed skill'.$counter.' collapse">'."\n\r";

            foreach ($all as $skill => $skill_value)
            {
                foreach ($skill_value as $name => $competency)
                {
                    if($name != $countStaff)
                    {
                        echo "<colgroup></colgroup>";
                        $countStaff = $name;
                    }
                }
            }

            echo '<thead>'."\n\r".'<tr>'."\n\r";
            echo '<th></th>'."\n\r";

            foreach ($all as $skill => $skill_value)
            {

                foreach ($skill_value as $name => $competency)
                {

                     if($name != $staff_name)
                     {
                         echo '<th><h2><a href="/users/'.$userID[$name].'">'.$name.'</a></h2></th>'."\n\r";

                     }
                        $staff_name = $name;
                }
            }

            echo '</tr>'."\n\r";
            echo '</thead>'."\n\r"; 
            echo '<tbody>'."\n\r";

            foreach ($all as $skill => $skill_value)
            {
                echo '<tr>'."\n\r";
                echo '<td>'.$skill .'</td>'."\n\r";

                foreach ($skill_value as $key => $value)
                {
                    echo $value;
                }
                echo '</tr>'."\n\r";
            }

            echo '</tbody>'."\n\r";

            echo '</table>'."\n\r";
            echo '</div>'."\n\r";
        }

    } else {
        echo "no skills avaliable";            
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? is there an easier way to group result sets in arrays than the way I am doing it?

Comment: what is the difference between the first and second example? Did you change smth in the raw data? Could you add that?

Comment: First one is edited to work correctly, second is actual result.

Comment: Edited via photoshop/whatever?

Comment: @user3528269 - yes